# How to adjust the risk table title position using package (survminer) in R?

Tags: r

I would like to create a Kaplan-Meier plot with a number at risk table using survminer. However I could not adjust the position of the title of risk table.

That is my code:

```
library(survminer)

library(survival)

fit<- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)

ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung, risk.table = TRUE, pval = TRUE, conf.int = TRUE, tables.theme = theme_cleantable())
```

I want to change **figure 1** to **figure 2**:

[image]

Comment: See here https://github.com/kassambara/survminer/issues/246